# Trying to close down and re-open Google Chrome - not working

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, windows-task-scheduler

I have a requirement to close down, and re-open Google Chrome in full-screen mode (via Windows Scheduler).

The code I have is in a PowerShell script file (`.ps1`):

```
# Close Google Chrome
Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }

# Wait for a few seconds to ensure Chrome is fully closed
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# Reopen Google Chrome in full-screen mode
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList "--start-fullscreen"
```

It is not closing down Chrome however.

Can you see anything wrong with the code? Or is it possible to add a log to view any errors?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: That code doesn't belong in a batch file, (`.bat`, `.cmd`). It is PowerShell code, and belongs is a powershell script instead, (`.ps1`).

Comment: BTW, why not simply use ```Stop-Process -Name "chrome"``` instead of ```Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }```

Comment: @Compo thank you - it is a PS1 script, and your suggestion worked.  Please add as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I have once again re-added the [[tag:batch-file]] tag. The main issue, and therefore main solution was 100% to do with you running this as an intended batch file. By removing that tag, you have essentially made the question and answer redundant. If you are happy with accepting your mistake, simply delete your question instead.

Comment: @Compo, there are scenarios where `.CloseMainWindow()` isn't honored (it is just a _request_ to close the window, it isn't enforced). By contrast, `Stop-Process` _forcefully kills_ a process, which may or may not be acceptable. I've removed the tag again, and have edited the question body to remove the batch-file confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code works in principle, but the [`.CloseMainWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow) method only *requests* that a target process' main window close, it doesn't *enforce it*.

  - Notably, the request will *not* be honored if:

    - A Chrome window puts up a confirmation dialog before closing.
    - A window has become unresponsive.
  - On the plus side, if the request *is* honored, you've allowed the processes to shut down *gracefully*, thereby avoiding *potential data loss*.
- If you're comfortable with *forcefully terminating* all Chrome processes - at the risk of potential data loss - you can use [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) instead, as [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) suggests:

  ```bash
  # Forcefully terminates all Chrome processes - RISK OF DATA LOSS
  Stop-Process -Name chrome
  ```

You can *combine* the two approaches, if you want to give the Chrome processes a chance to shut down gracefully first, and *fall back* to forceful termination:

```bash
# Try graceful shutdown first.
$null = 
  try { (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore chrome).CloseMainWindow() } catch { }

# Sleep a little, to see if the graceful shutdown succeeded.
# Note: You may have to tweak the sleep intervals.
Start-Sleep 1

# If any Chrome processes still exist, terminate them forcefully now.
if ($chromeProcesses = Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore chrome) {
  # Terminate forcefully, and abort if that fails.
  $chromeProcesses | Stop-Process -ErrorAction Stop
  # Sleep again, to wait for the terminated processes to disappear.
  Start-Sleep 1
}

# Restart Chrome.
# Note that with Start-Process you normally do not need the full path.
Start-Process chrome '--start-fullscreen'
```

Note the use of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to simplify the code that calls `.CloseMainWindow()`:
`(Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore chrome).CloseMainWindow()`
automatically calls `.CloseMainWindow()` on *each* process object returned by `Get-Process`; the `try` / `catch` enclosure ensures that no error occurs if there happen to be *no* matching processes, because attempting to call a method on `$null` would cause an error.